# Is it possible to do a git clone using Magit in a directory which is not under version control?

Tags: magit, git, directories

Suppose I am in a folder called `local-projects`. Using the terminal, I can do:

```bash
[pedro@system:~/quicklisp/local-projects]$ pwd

/home/pedro/quicklisp/local-projects
```

An important information to highlight is that *local-projects* folder is **not** under git control.
Even so and still using the terminal, I can do:

```bash
[pedro@system:~/quicklisp/local-projects]$ git clone git@github.com:muyinliu/jsown-utils.git
```

This works, Ok.

So, I wished I could do `git clone` using Magit great interface. There is a command for `C` (capitalized C) which is to clone.

Thus, using dired I decide to go to the folder  `~/quicklisp/local-projects`. But, when I execute the command to invoke Magit with `magit-status`, Magit asks me the following:

```bash
Create repository in /home/pedro/quicklisp/local-projects/? (y or n)
```

I answer `n`. In shell, there is no such a question. Not sure if I missed something, but it seems inappropriate to answer `y`, thus, I choose `n`.

Did I miss something?

Is it possible to achieve the same result as `git clone ...` in shell using Magit [1] ?

[1] - By the same result I am including the side effects of the process.

Comment: The question isn't related to Emacs or Magit. The are many layers to unpack here: version control systems, git and git interfaces (command line, magit, etc). Magit asks you if you want to clone the repository in the current directory. In the command line, cloning the "tomato" repository means creating a new "tomato" folder and dumping it in there. Does that make sense?

Comment: Concretely, use `M-x magit-clone` and define the destination folder instead of running `magit-status` from a given folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are doing `magit-status`, presumably so you can use the `C` binding to do the clone. But the doc for `magit-status` says:

> If the current directory isn’t located within a Git repository,
> then prompt for an existing repository or an arbitrary directory,
> depending on option ‘magit-repository-directories’, and show the
> status of the selected repository instead.

If you did `M-x magit-clone` directly (i.e. what `C` is bound to in `magit-mode-map`), then you won't get the question.